# imagePickerController delegate not called,Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a profile picture which also acts as a button, when the person clicks the picture the image selector shows up and they can choose the picture they want to use as their profile picture, but the `imagePickerController` is not being called, and the Parse db image file is not being called. Why is this happening, how can I fix it?

```
class ProfileView: UIViewController,  UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
 func userchange(sender: AnyObject){
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum){
       // imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

        let user = PFUser.currentUser()
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.05)
        let imageFile = PFFile(name:"image.jpg", data:imageData!)
        user!["ProPic"] = imageFile;
        imageFile.save()
        //NOTHING IS BEING PRINTED
        print("called")
        user!.saveInBackgroundWithBlock(nil)


        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: check that you were added the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` in your class

Comment: // imagePicker.delegate = self
why is commented ?

Comment: you were added the  `imagePicker .delegate = self` in your class, it called your delegates

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I don't follow

Comment: @MejdiLassidi, I get an error when I uncomment it

Comment: ya Now I got it bro,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in `swift 2.0` and onwards if you using any delegates for example `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` , you need to compulsory implement the delegate methods , else dont use or dont add in your viewcontroller, this is the concept , now follow this
some example

**Step-1**

add `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate` in your view Controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
```

**Step-2**

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

imagePicker.delegate = self // Its Manotary
}
```

**Step-3**

```
 // Present the Image picker controller

@IBAction func loadImageButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Step-4**

```
// call the delegate method for pick the image

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    imageView.image = pickedImage
}

dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Step-5**

```
// finally dismiss the Imagepicker controller

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController)    {
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```